# The 1024x600 LCD display on my Raspberry Pi 4B is not displaying the proper resolution; it appears too small

Tags: pi-4, lcd, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B running Bookworm OS and recently acquired a new 1024x600 LCD [display](https://www.conrad.de/de/p/joy-it-rb-lcd7-2-touchscreen-modul-17-8-cm-7-zoll-1024-x-600-pixel-passend-fuer-entwicklungskits-raspberry-pi-1543962.html?hk=SEM&WT.mc_id=google_pla&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwnOipBhBQEiwACyGLusSjFDh5l1qGmtRh8XuHzseJLDwy5Cqf1m-sYg1xfH6NUuI-IioiDhoCPDkQAvD_BwE). However, upon turning on the display, the icons appear too small, making them difficult to press. I followed [this method](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=358269) by adding "video=HDMI-A-1:1024x600@60D" to the beginning of /boot/cmdline.txt. While this solution worked for two days, the resolution reverted back to the previous setting. Any ideas?

Image below showing the small icons:
[image]

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Comment: `not displaying the proper resolution` ... it does not look like a resolution problem ... the icons just need to be made bigger ... if the resolution is 1024x600, then you don't want to be changing that, because the desktop fits the display

Comment: @jsotola Any idea on how to change the size of the icons?

Comment: that would depend on the DM (desktop manager)

Answer (score 0):

The size of icons has nothing to do with screen resolution.

This is set through the `Appearance Settings` menu, although you should select Defaults for your Screen Size (probably Small) first.

You should have been prompted to set these on first boot.

Incidentally is is generally unnecessary (and undesirable) to FORCE resolution - this should be selected automatically through the screen EDID settings. If you later want to change this (usually only appropriate for very large screens) this can also be done through Appearance Settings.

Comment: The thing is that adjusting the settings don't change the resolution or icons size, then I rebooted the Raspi and it didn't change anything when adjusting the settings